# Pass Types as arguments to a function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

The following two functions are extremely similar. They read from a [String] n elements, either [Int] or [Float]. How can I factor the common code out? I don't know of any mechanism in Haskell that supports passing types as arguments.

```
readInts n stream = foldl next ([], stream) [1..n]
  where
    next (lst, x:xs) _ = (lst ++ [v], xs)
      where
        v = read x :: Int

readFloats n stream = foldl next ([], stream) [1..n]
  where
    next (lst, x:xs) _ = (lst ++ [v], xs)
      where
        v = read x :: Float
```

I am at a beginner level of Haskell, so any comments on my code are welcome.

Comment: You don't need to fold here, you can get by with a simple map. e.g. `map read stream :: [Int]` Also you may want to look into why you want to use foldr in Haskell rather than foldl.

Comment: @EdwardKmett Thanks for your suggestion. What I really want is to read only first n elements, and return the list and the rest of the stream. I was super sleepy yesterday, and couldn't think through. I think you want to say that with foldr I can use the constructor : directly right? I later rewrote it as `(map read firstn, rest) where (firstn, rest) = splitAt n stream`, quite similar to what you suggested.

Comment: You do not need to nest `where`; you can put `next (lst, x:xs) _ = ...` and `v = ...` in consecutive lines.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Haskell supports a high degree of polymorphism.  In particular

```
readAny n stream = foldl next ([], stream) [1..n]
  where
    next (lst, x:xs) _ = (lst ++ [v], xs)
      where
        v = read x
```

has type

```
readAny :: (Enum b, Num b, Read a) => b -> [String] -> ([a], [String])
```

thus

```
readInts :: (Enum b, Num b) => b -> [String] -> ([Int], [String])
readInts = readAny

readFloats :: (Enum b, Num b) => b -> [String] -> ([Float], [String])
readFloats = readAny
```

you dont need to specialize the type.  Haskell will automatically infer the most general type possible, and the `readAny` here will do what you want.

It is not possible to pass types as arguments in Haskell.  Rarely would you need to.  For those few cases where it is necessary you can simulate the behavior by passing a value with the desired type.

Haskell has "return type polymorphism" so you really shouldn't worry about "passing the type"--odds are that functions will do what you want without you telling them to.

Comment: Ironically, *passing the type*  is in some implementation dependent way what happens behind the scenes, hence the question is not that far off the mark ....

Comment: Many implementations dont so much pass the type as pass a type consistent witness for the type-class values.  Something like `id` doesn't need to know the type of its arguments at all (so long as everything is the same size)

Comment: That's what I meant with *implementation dependent way*. But *id*, having no constraints, gets passed nothing at all, I guess. The type guarantees that id is not going to do anything with it's argument that would need more information than just "it's some value", but this should be implied.

Comment: Just for any future readers that may see this question, there *is* a way to pass explicit type parameters. You can set `-XTypeApplications` and use `read @T` to request that `read` be instantiated at the explicitly given type `T`. This works with `-XScopedTypeVariables` and `-XPartialTypeSignatures`, too.

Comment: is it perhaps `readInts :: Int -> [String] -> ([Int], [String])` (and similar for `readFloats`)?

Answer (score 9):

Basically what you want is to not explicitly declare the type.  Instead, defer declaring the type and let the inference engine take over for you.  Also, I think you are conflating fold with map.   This is how I would approach it.

```
readList' :: Read a => [String] -> [a]
readList' = map read


ints = readList' ["1", "2"] :: [Int] -- [1, 2]

floats = readList' ["1.0", "2.0"] :: [Float] -- [1.0, 2.0]
```

To read only n things from the stream, use `take`