# Haskell: function that takes a type argument and returns a value depending on that type?

Tags: haskell, types, syntax, typeclass

The question is basically: how do I write a function `f` in Haskell that takes a value `x` and a type argument `T`, and then returns a value `y = f x T`  which depends both on `x` and `T`, without explicitly ascribing the type of the entire expression `f x T`? (The `f x T` is not valid Haskell, but a placeholder-pseudo-syntax).

Consider the following situation. Suppose that I have a typeclass `Transform a b` which provides a single function `transform :: a -> b`. Suppose that I also have a bunch of `instances` of `Transform` for various combinations of types `a b`. Now I'd like to chain multiple `transform`-functions together. However, I want the `Transform`-instance to be selected depending on the previosly constructed chain and on the *next* type in the chain of transformations. Ideally, this would give me something like this (with hypothetical functions `source` and `migrate` and invalid syntax `<< >>` for "passing type parameters"; `migrate` is used as infix-operation):

```
z = source<<A>> migrate <<B>> ... migrate <<Z>>
```

Here, `source` somehow generates values of type `A`, and each `migrate<<T>>` is supposed to find an instance `Transform S T` and append it to the chain.

**What I came up with so far:** It actually (almost) works in Haskell using type ascriptions. Consider the following (compilable) example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

-- compiles with: 
-- The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.2.2

-- A typeclass with two type-arguments
class Transform a b where
  transform :: a -> b

-- instances of `T` forming a "diamond"
--
--            String
--              / \ 
--             /   \ 
--            /     \
--           /       \
--     Double         Rational
--           \       /
--            \     /
--             \   /
--              \ /
--              Int
--
instance Transform String Double where
  transform = read

instance Transform String Rational where
  transform = read -- turns out to be same as fo `Double`, but pretend it's different

instance Transform Double Int where
  transform = round

instance Transform Rational Int where
  transform = round -- pretend it's different from `Double`-version


-- A `MigrationPath` to `b` is
-- essentially some data source and
-- a chain of transformations 
-- supplied by typeclass `T`
-- 
-- The `String` here is a dummy for a more
-- complex operation that is roughly `a -> b`
data MigrationPath b = Source b 
                     | forall a . Modify (MigrationPath a) (a -> b)

-- A function that appends a transformation `T` from `a` to `b`
-- to a `MigrationPath a`
migrate :: Transform a b => MigrationPath a -> MigrationPath b
migrate mpa = Modify mpa transform


-- Build two paths along the left and right side 
-- of the diamond
leftPath :: MigrationPath Int
leftPath = migrate ((migrate ((Source "3.333") :: (MigrationPath String))) :: (MigrationPath Double))

rightPath :: MigrationPath Int
rightPath = migrate((migrate ((Source "10/3") :: (MigrationPath String))) :: (MigrationPath Rational))

main = putStrLn "it compiles, ship it"
```

In this example, we define `Transform` instances such that they form two possible `MigrationPath`s from `String` to `Int`. Now, we (as a human beings) want to exercise our free will, and force the compiler to pick either the left path, or the right path in this chain of transformations.

This is even kind-of possible in this case. We can force the compiler to create the right chain by constructing an "onion" of constraints from type ascriptions:

```
leftPath :: MigrationPath Int
leftPath = migrate ((migrate ((Source "3.333") :: (MigrationPath String))) :: (MigrationPath Double))
```

However, I find it very sub-optimal for two reasons:

- The AST `(migrate ... (Type))` grows to both sides around the `Source` (this is a minor issue, it probably can be rectified using infix operators with left-associativity).
- More severe: if the type of `MigrationPath` stored not only the target type, but also the source type, with the type-ascription approach we would have to repeat every type in the chain *twice*, which would make the entire approach too awkward to use.

**Question:** is there any way to construct the above chain of transformations in such a way that only "the next type", and not the entire "type of the `MigrationPath T`" has to be ascribed?

**What I'm not asking:** It is clear to me that in the above toy-example, it would be easier to define functions `transformStringToInt :: String -> Int` etc, and then just chain them together using `.`. This is not the question. The question is: how do I force the compiler to *generate* the expressions corresponding to `transformStringToInt` when I specify *just the type*. In the actual application, I want to specify only the types, and use a set of rather complicated rules to derive an appropriate instance with the right `transform`-function.

---

**(Optional):** Just to give an impression of what I'm looking for. Here is a completely analogous example from `Scala`:

```
 // typeclass providing a transformation from `X` to `Y`
 trait Transform[X, Y] {
   def transform(x: X): Y
 }

 // Some data migration path ending with `X`
 sealed trait MigrationPath[X] {
   def migrate[Y](implicit t: Transform[X, Y]): MigrationPath[Y] = Migrate(this, t)
 }
 case class Source[X](x: X) extends MigrationPath[X]
 case class Migrate[A, X](a: MigrationPath[A], t: Transform[A, X]) extends MigrationPath[X]


 // really bad implementation of fractions
 case class Q(num: Int, denom: Int) {
   def toInt: Int = num / denom
 }

 // typeclass instances for various type combinations
 implicit object TransformStringDouble extends Transform[String, Double] {
   def transform(s: String) = s.toDouble
 }

 implicit object TransformStringQ extends Transform[String, Q] {
   def transform(s: String) = Q(s.split("/")(0).toInt, s.split("/")(1).toInt)
 }

 implicit object TransformDoubleInt extends Transform[Double, Int] {
   def transform(d: Double) = d.toInt
 }

 implicit object TransformQInt extends Transform[Q, Int] {
   def transform(q: Q) = q.toInt
 }

 // constructing migration paths that yield `Int`
 val leftPath = Source("3.33").migrate[Double].migrate[Int]
 val rightPath = Source("10/3").migrate[Q].migrate[Int]
```

Notice how `migrate`-method requires nothing but the "next type", not the type ascription for the entire expression constructed so far.

---

**Related:** I want to note that this question is not an exact duplicate of ["Pass Types as arguments to a function in Haskell?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039274/pass-types-as-arguments-to-a-function-in-haskell). My use case is a bit different. I also tend to disagree with the answers there that "it's not possible / you don't need it", because I actually *do have a solution*, it's just rather ugly from the purely syntactical point of view.

Comment: Oh dear, that question you linked is a bit outdated. There's a language extension for this now.

Comment: @HTNW If it's solvable by a one-line simple language extension, I'll take it ;) It's quite possible that my Haskell is not quite up-to-date, I'm currently just investigating whether a very specific piece of code could be converted from Scala to Haskell without too much pain.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `TypeApplications` language extension, which allows you to explicitly instantiate individual type variables. The following code seems to have the flavor you want, and it typechecks:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForAll, FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeApplications #-}

class Transform a b where
  transform :: a -> b

instance Transform String Double where
  transform = read

instance Transform String Rational where
  transform = read

instance Transform Double Int where
  transform = round

instance Transform Rational Int where
  transform = round

transformTo :: forall b a. Transform a b => a -> b
transformTo = transform

stringToInt1 :: String -> Int
stringToInt1 = transform . transformTo @Double

stringToInt2 :: String -> Int
stringToInt2 = transform . transformTo @Rational
```

The definition `transformTo` uses an explicit use of `forall` to flip `b` and `a` so that `TypeApplications` will instantiate `b` first.

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Nice trick with the flipped type arguments; Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Use the type applications syntax extension.

```
> :set -XTypeApplications
> transform @_ @Int (transform @_ @Double "9007199254740993")
9007199254740992
> transform @_ @Int (transform @_ @Rational "9007199254740993%1")
9007199254740993
```

Inputs carefully chosen to give the lie to your "turns out to be the same as for `Double`" comment, even after correcting for syntax differences in the input.

Comment: You can use an explicit `forall` to set the order of arguments. I also think that should be mandatory for any function meant to be used with `TypeApplications`.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia Sure, or just give the typeclass arguments in the other order in the first place. On the other hand, knowing the type-hole application syntax is handy anyway, since it's not obvious to me why return type is obviously the correct thing to disambiguate for `transform`. One might just as well want to disambiguate input type in some other part of the code as far as I can tell.